# SQLException while trying to insert a double value into Oracle database

Tags: java, sql, string, oracle11g, ora-00913

I have to develop a small program that inserts some data into an Oracle database. Unfortunately I have some trouble with a SQL `Statement` and the execution of it. This is the code I am using:

```
db.execute(
    String.format("INSERT INTO tops VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, %f.00, '%s', TO_TIMESTAMP('%s', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))", 
        item.getID(),
        item.getTitle(),
        this.elements,
        item.getSize(),
        item.getEntity(),
        timestamp.toString()));
```

This is the part where the execution should work but I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00913: Zu viele Werte
```

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Zu%20viele%20Werte) for exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00913: Too many values
```

Comment: I think you can leave the quotes away from the string values.

Comment: Sounds like the values you want to insert don't match the table schema. (too many values)

Comment: Use prepared statements, string manipulation is a really bad idea

Comment: You should always specify the columns you're inserting into. Otherwise your code will break as soon as someone adds a new column to the table.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: no, he can't leave the quotes away! He uses a simple SQL query string, and without the quotes, the Java `String.format` - not _knowing_ that this is an SQL string that is being assembled - will not insert the quotes...

Comment: Oooops... I just glanced at the code. That's **very** bad. SQL Injection and all that! Please use a PreparedStatement. It's actually easier that way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use prepared statements like this as suggested by Guallaume on the comment;

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
Connection conn = null;

try{
     //if you have a method that creates a connection for you.
     conn = getConnection();
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tops(id, title, elements, size, entity, timeStamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     pstmt.setInt(1,item.getID());

     //Assuming that title is a String data type
     pstmt.setString(2,item.getTitle());
     pstmt.setString(3,this.elements);
     pstmt.setDouble(4,item.getSize()); // <--- JDBC will make sure this works

     //assuming Entity data type is String
     pstmt.setString(5,item.getEntity());

     //if your timestamp's string format is 
     //well formed, you may insert as a string.
     pstmt.setString(6,timestamp.toString());
     pstmt.executeUpdate();
}catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}finally{  
     try{
         pstmt.close();
     }catch(Exception e){}

     try{
         conn.close();
     }catch(Exception e){}
 }
```

Comment: I hope the formating is a little better. As you can see, you need to know state the column names that you intend to insert values for in your prepared statement query. e.g `INSERT INTO tops(id, title, elements, size, entity, timeStamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)"` The columns here I assumed are id, title,elemets, size, entity and timestamp. And the `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)` tells java that the values will go in there.   `pstmt.setInt(1,item.getID());` sets the 1st value, `pstmt.setString(2,item.getTitle());` sets the second value, ` pstmt.setString(3,this.elements);` sets the 3rd value and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use this syntax

```sql
INSERT INTO table VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

Use this one instead

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

Tables may change. Fields may get added / removed / reordered - in case of which your `INSERT` statement would break again.

Of course, as others suggest, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection and syntax errors... Imagine, `item.getTitle()` was any of these

```
"a', 'b";
"a'); DROP TABLE tops;' ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should use PreparedStatements, believe us...

In this case, however, the problem is very likely, that your locale uses the comma (`,`) character for the decimal point..

So 1/4 becomes: `0,25`, not `0.25` as the DB would like!

Why is this a problem?

Look at this:

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES ( 0,25 );
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES ( 0, 25);
```

Both are treated as having **2** values, just the first one is not obvious for us, who use the comma as a decimal point... So you have to change the comma to a dot, or change the locale to US.

Correct:

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES ( 0.25);
```

You can specify the locale of the string formatting using [String.format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) by supplying an appropriate locale.

Comment: @LukasEder I'm not a genius - I just had a lot of strange issues to deal with :) Here in Hungary, we also use the comma as the decimal point... (I did say out loud some _non-politically-correct expressions_ even in front of my most respected colleagues though, when I first found out that this situation can cause troubles...)

Comment: @LukasEder the longer (and louder, not to mention) version was exacly how my long rant started about this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This format string corrected.

```
"INSERT INTO tops VALUES (%f, '%s', %f, %.2f, '%s', TO_TIMESTAMP('%s', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))"
```

Don't use many values for each argument, use exactly one for each one, total six values.